# Should I check length of Name on Registration page?

Tags: php, validation, string-length

I had more of a general question not exactly about my code. I was adding validation to my registration code for my site (checking for length and stripping out illegal characters). But I was wondering if I ask for the persons name first & last. Should I check the length of the characters on the name fields?

And if so what would be good min and max length's for names. I was thinking 3-20 characters. But I really dont want to limit the names if someone really does have a name longer then 20 characters. Any feedback would be great thanks :)

Comment: Why would you want to limit lenght of name field?

Comment: And some people have also names of two chars like `Jo`.

Comment: Not to mention `Bo`, as in `Derek` ;-)

Comment: Wouldn't I need to have at least a max length? To avoid errors when submitting to mysql table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find `VARCHAR(32)` for first name and last *real* name fields to be sufficient, and the only thing I would suggest doing to them is a run through `htmlspecialchars()` before inserting because some people legitimately have "strange" accented or non-ascii characters in their names that most people don't take into account with checks like `preg_match('/[a-z]+/i', $name);`, and a combination of parameterized queries [you're using those, right] and `htmlspecialchars()` should protect you from first and second order injection attacks.

You can use [`iconv()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.iconv.php) to transliterate/mangle their names into ASCII, but that's hit and miss, plus a pain in the ass, plus some people might take offense at that.

On the other hand if you're worried about space-efficiency with your field length you should know that the `VAR` in `VARCHAR` means 'variable length' and a `VARCHAR(32)` field containing 'Ted' will only take up [4 bytes of storage](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/char.html).